# Remove the Extra Whitespace Surrounding Iframes?

Tags: html, css, iframe, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am using iframes in my page, and have stumbled across a weird issue. I set the iframe css like so

```
iframe {
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
    background: blue; /* this is just to make the frames easier to see */
    border: none;
}
```

However, there is still whitespace surrounding the iframe. I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox, and it's the same. I searched around, and I couldn't find anything. This whitespace doesn't show up in the Chrome console, either.
Also, I already have the following CSS as well:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mM6AB/1/)

Comment: [Tested](http://jsfiddle.net/u82Qh/) on chrome, IE and FF (on my end) can not visibly see a border. It's probably the container it's in. (I know I set a size, but my anticipation is that an iframe's margin would expand its parent to accommodate--no such outcome.)

Comment: @BradChristie what should I do then? The iframes are just in my body tag.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle duplicating exactly what you have? (Place the entire html source in the top left window and click save and provide that link.)

Comment: Please post your html content, bit difficult to figure out [http://jsfiddle.net/yELzF/]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Having just seen your fiddle your issue is because you are using `display:inline-block`. This takes whitespace in your html into account. `display:inline-block` is notorious for being difficult and has dodgy browser support.

**Option 1:**
Try removing the white space in your html can sometimes sort the problem.

**Option 2:**
Using a different display property such as `display:block` will definitely sort the problem. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mM6AB/3/

Comment: Did you try `display:block`. Because that should definitely fix the problem.

Comment: yes it does for me in Chrome, too! I don't know why that works, but it does! Can you put that as an answer, so I can mark it as correct? I also had to remove the DOCTYPE, but that's fine.

Comment: I had the same problem without using `display:inline-block` but adding `display:block` like you said fixed it for me too :)

Comment: Really helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 18):

```
iframe { display:block; }
```

iframe is a inline element

Answer (score 16):

When you are using an inline element, the whitespace might be from the "line" the element is part of (ie. the space below the baseline).  The solution then is to add this to its parent element.

```
line-height: 0;
```

Comment: Didn't help much for an iframe.

Answer (score 3):

Bit difficult to solve without your html content, but give this a try:

```
iframe {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    background: blue; /* this is just to make the frames easier to see */
    border: 0px !important;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Adding the `!important` will force the style, coz my guess is that your styles are overwriting each other.

Answer (score 3):

try using a div with `overflow: hidden;` surrounding the `<iframe>`, like

```
<div style="height: 29px; overflow: hidden;">
   <iframe frameborder=0 allowtransparency=yes scrolling=no src="../hng_frames/copyright_part.html" width="980" height="30">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I closed this question a while ago. Also, why would that remotely help?

Comment: What he's saying is that in times when you have an iFrame that is specifically set to 300px, but the browser is rendering it with a 4px border, you can set the parent div to 300px and the it is now impossible for the border to show on the iFrame.

Comment: In my case it did help, though I'm not sure why

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that whitespace is actually the outside margin of the document loaded in the . Try styling the loaded document (CSS styling the **source page**) with:

```
html, body {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

quoted from stackoverflow.com [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022017/white-space-is-still-present-around-the-iframe-border-even-after-after-setting-f)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by floating the frame element

```
iframe {

    margin: none;
    padding: none;
    border: none;
    line-height: 0;
    float: left; 
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you changed and why it works.

Comment: This is why it's ok to add to old questions: the explanation of adding `float:left;`

Comment: `float: left;` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the given answers provided a solution for me (I also stumbled across the weird margin issue when implementing an iFrame) I found this to be working fine:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="/something"></iframe>
```

*marginwidth* and *marginheight* are not valid / officially supported HTML5-tags but they work just fine in my tests...

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. marginwidth and marginheight to "0".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line-height setting, try adding `line-height: 0;` to the iframe container.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it on the page that you call, not in the iframe.

```
<iframe src=test.html></iframe>
```

Then in test.html, only `margin:0` is sufficient.

```
body { margin: 0}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `html, body {margin:0px;}`