# Space between frames

Tags: html, css

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<frameset rows="26%,24%,*" noresize border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
<frame src="frame_a.html" target="_self" name="logo" scrolling="auto">
<frame src="frame_b.html" target="_self" name="menu" scrolling="no">
<frame src="frame_c.html" name="images_slider" scrolling="auto" target="_self">
</frameset>
</html>
```

But still there is space between frames how to remove that space??? I want to remove space between menu and header which are frame a and frame b

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the Extra Whitespace Surrounding Iframes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735022/remove-the-extra-whitespace-surrounding-iframes)

Comment: Just a little Google : `remove space between iframe` and you will found answer, and more... and see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290214/html-strange-space-between-iframe-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Set the body and html margins to `0` within the `frame_#.html` files and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Update the rows property in your frameset element

`<frameset rows="26%,24%,*" noresize border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">`

from: 26%
to: 45

[Example](http://liveweave.com/R823Hc)

I am using pixels instead of percentages (e.g. 45px = 45) for spacing between frame a and frame b.
You can adjust the 2nd parameter (24%) accordingly for spacing between frame b and frame c.

[Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frameset_rows.asp)

Hope that helps!