# How to remove whitespace while using iframes side by side in HTML5

Tags: css, html, iframe

How to remove the whitespace from two frames placed side by side?

I tried:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="l" src="l.htm" style="width:10%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe name="c" src="c.htm" style="width:75%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe name="r" src="r.htm" style="width:15%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I also looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6735357/8995989), but it is saying that by using display property as `display: block` there will be no whitespace. But if I use that property my frames will be *below each other not side by side*. And I want my frames side by side as *10%, 75%, 15%*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace in HTML source code is significant.

Compare these two paragraphs:

```html
<p>
a
b
c
</p>
<p>abc</p>
```

Remove the whitespace between the inline items in the source code to remove it from the rendered display.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="l" src="l.htm" style="width:10%;" scrolling="no"></iframe><iframe name="c" src="c.htm" style="width:75%;" scrolling="no"></iframe><iframe name="r" src="r.htm" style="width:15%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```